# Disable Javascript Popup function wordpress Without Deleting the Code

Tags: javascript

I need your help. I have this code and I want to disable it for some time. I tried to uncomment a few lines, but it was still displaying. Please is there a single line here where I can comment it out to stop displaying on my site?

What if I comment out `// console.log(('1');` Will it work?

```
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('document').ready(function($){
            setInterval(function(){ 
                var popupCounter = sessionStorage.getItem("popupCounter");        
                if (popupCounter == '' || popupCounter == null) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        jQuery('.exit-poup-code-wrap').fadeIn();
                        sessionStorage.setItem("popupCounter",'1');                 
                    }, 1000);               
                }
               
                if(popupCounter == '1'){
                //  do nothing      
                return false;
                    clearInterval();
                }
                  console.log('1');
            }, 1000);
            $('body').on('click','.popup_exit_close', function(){
                $('.exit-poup-code-wrap').fadeOut();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

in wordpress functions.php. The issue is that I don't want it to display/popup for now. And I don't want to delete it because I will still need it.

Please which line should I comment out, so that this popup won't display until I uncomment the line. My javascript knowledge is below basic.

I uncommented some lines, but it didn't work, I didn't want to destroy the code. I hired someone to help develop it, but I can no longer hire him.

Comment: FYI, I removed the PHP tag since the question seem to be about JS specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Code:**

```
jQuery('.exit-poup-code-wrap').fadeIn();
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer and explain how it solves the issue.

Comment: I comment out the following code 

// jQuery('.exit-poup-code-wrap').fadeIn(); and yes i didn't see the popup again.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/* codes */` to comment out multiple lines so that you can comment all codes without much editing:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
codes
codes
*/
</script>
```

Alternatively, you should learn how to toggle comments for multiple lines quickly in your text editor / IDE.

If you really want to minify the modification, you can add a `return` at beginning so that the function stops before doing anything:

```js
        jQuery('document').ready(function($){
            return;
            setInterval(function(){
```

Or comment out `jQuery('.exit-poup-code-wrap').fadeIn()`, which shows the popup. Reference: [.fadeIn() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

```js
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        // jQuery('.exit-poup-code-wrap').fadeIn();
                        sessionStorage.setItem("popupCounter",'1');                 
                    }, 1000);
```